# Snapshot of BTRFS Device on top of luks Volume

Tags: backup, partition, snapshot, btrfs, luks

I have the following problem:

I can't figure out, how to create a snapshot of a btrfs volume residing on a crypted disk.

This is the setup:

/dev/sdb is a 1TB USB 3 disk.
it has a partition /dev/sdb1, which fills the whole space.

This partition was overwritten with random data before creating a luks device with

cryptsetup luksFormat -v -y -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 /dev/sdb1

it was then opened with

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 platte
```

and a filesystem was created via

```
mkfs.btrfs -L MuPla /dev/mapper/platte
```

/dev/mapper/platte mounts nicely, i was able to fill it with files last night.

At this point i wanted to make a snapshot to be able to track file changes. Here comes the problem:

```
btrfs device scan
```

does not list the filesystem.

Neither

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /dev/mapper/platte snap-2014-11-10
```

nor

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /run/media/mymountpoint snap-2014-11-10
```

work Could you help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error output & logs would have been too helpful, wouldn't they?  A "It doesn't work" without any information would have been better :-)

Comment: Hm, this question has been asked 2 years ago. I don't have logs from back then and even I can't remember how I finally circumvented the problem. But I think, if I have had any output or relevant logs, I would have posted them. In other words: I don't think an actual error occurred; I believe there was a bug which just made btrfs subvolume return an empty set.